# Is there some slick way to evaluate this complex integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Evaluate:
$$\int_{|z|=2} \frac{z^2}{(z-1)^2(z+1)^3} \ dz$$

The residue theorem looks promising, but the two poles are of order 2 and 3. Is there a way to compute this integrand's residues about $z = 1$ and $z= -1$ without computing repeated derivatives of $ \frac{z^2}{(z+1)^3}$, and $ \frac{z^2}{(z-1)^2}$?

Or we could just compute the Laurent series, but is there an easy way to do that? Even using partial fraction decomposition and then expanding appropriate terms as Taylor series seems cumbersome, partially because of the $z^2$ in the numerator. Is there a better way?

Comment: The integration path encloses both poles and the integrand function is $O\left(\frac{1}{|z|^3}\right)$ as $|z|\to +\infty$. It follows that the wanted integral is simply zero. This is an abstract duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458041/integral-of-int-c-frac1z2-z-dz-where-c-is-a-circle-of-radius-2/2458052#2458052

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may as well integrate over $|z| = R$ for any $R > 2$ (why?). What happens when $R \to \infty$? (Estimate the integrand on a large circle.)

Comment: Something like: $\frac{z^2}{(z-1)^2(z+1)^3} \approx \frac{1}{(z+1)^3}$ when $z >> 2$ ? And then integrate $\frac{1}{(z+1)^3}$ (directly or with residues?) over $|z| = R$, for some arbitrary $R$, and then take the limit of the result as $R \to \infty$ ? Hmm, something's not right

Comment: More like: $|f| \le C/R^3$ for some constant $C$, so $| \int f \,dz | \le 2\pi R \cdot C/R^3 \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: Ah yes, that is precisely the kind of slick answer I sought.